# Compare row with next row and create a new column from results, using Python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, window-functions

I would like to compare two consecutive rows from two columns, and if they are the same value, then create a new column based on the difference between a third column value. See input and expected output below:

**Input:**

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'Account Number': [123,123,123,456,456,456],  'Value':['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF'],'Positions':[10,10,20,20,20,15]})
```

**Expected Output:**

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'Account Number': [123,123,123,456,456,456],'Value':['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF'],'Positions':[10,10,20,20,20,15], 'new_col': [0,0,10,0,0,-5]})
```

In excel, the formula is simply:

```
IF(AND(B2=B1,C2=C1), D2-D1, 0)
```

where: B = Account Number, C = Value, D = new_col

I've tried two attempts so far - (1) using iloc (which is yielding an IndexError: Single positional indexer is out of bounds") and (2) using rolling(n) - but I'm not able to even compile. See below my attempt at (1) Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
a = 0
if a != len(df):
    for a in range(len(df)):
        df['new_col'] = np.where((df["Account Number"].iloc[a+1] == df["Account Number"].iloc[a]) and (df["Value"].iloc[a+1] == df["Value"].iloc[a]), df["Positions"].iloc[a+1] df["Positions"].iloc[a], 0)
        a+= 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop, you should use a simple and more performant pandas method called `.diff()`:

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('Account Number')['Positions'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Full code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account Number': [123,123,123,456,456,456],  'Value':['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF'],'Positions':[10,10,20,20,20,15]})
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('Account Number')['Positions'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
df
Out[1]: 
   Account Number Value  Positions  new_col
0             123   ABC         10        0
1             123   ABC         10        0
2             123   ABC         20       10
3             456   DEF         20        0
4             456   DEF         20        0
5             456   DEF         15       -5
```

Comment: Thanks David - However, this solution is not what I was looking for, because it doesn't check that (1) the current row and next row for 'Account Number' are the same AND (2) the current row and next row for 'Value' are the same. However, you bring up a good point about using the diff method as a way to do row-wise comparison, instead of looping. Would you know how to go about this?

Comment: @samoa_like_Moana easy! Just groupby Account Number. See updated answer!

Comment: Yes! Actually the groupby needs to have both 'Account Number' and 'Value', and then it is the solution. Thank you David!!

Answer (score 0):

for a in range(len(df)-1):

Notice the -1.
Without it - yes, you will run into an indexerror

Answer (score 0):

Looping over pandas structure in general should be avoided, but I don't know how to help you without a loop or reworking your data struct

```
new_col=[0]
for a in range(len(df)-1):
    if (df["Account Number"].iloc[a+1] == df["Account Number"].iloc[a]) and (df["Value"].iloc[a+1] == df["Value"].iloc[a]):
        new_col.append(df["Positions"].iloc[a+1] - df["Positions"].iloc[a])
    else:
        new_col.append(0)

df["new_col"]=new_col
print(df)
```

gives the following output

```
   Account Number Value  Positions  new_col
0             123   ABC         10        0
1             123   ABC         10        0
2             123   ABC         20       10
3             456   DEF         20        0
4             456   DEF         20        0
5             456   DEF         15       -5
```

Comment: I see that an answer leveraging pandas features has been posted. If you don't need the condition check you mentioned, you should go for David Erickson diff() solution. And if you don't it would still be good to find a way to avoid loops.

Comment: Thank you TriGiamp - this solution works great. Unfortunately, I do need the condition check.